# Trying to click through list of links in table - Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-detached-from-dom

I am trying to itirate through a list of links on a table and ensure the next page has ht ecorrect url but running into issues. One problem is that there are no good class names to work with so I have been using cy.xpath.

```js
//Loop through each element (This is a dynamic amount of elements)
cy.xpath('//span[text()="Id"]//following::a[contains(@href,"maps")]'.each($el) => { 
  cy.get($el).then(($btn) => {
    let id_text = $btn.text()
    
    //Check that the element is visible and click on it
    cy.get($el)
      .should('be.visible')
      .click()

    //Check that the url contains the text value of the element that was clicked on
    cy.url()
      .should('contain', id_text)
    
    })
  })
```

It works one time through and then gets tripped up saying the DOM element became detached

Comment: If you can add HTML maybe there might be a better way than xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, it may (probably isn't) the best way but hey it works! This loops through all numbers in the column I needed, goes into the next page, checks that the url contains the number it clicked on, then goes back.

```js
      //Get length of table
      cy.get('.MuiTableBody-root')
        .find('tr')
        .then((row) => {
          let num_rows = row.length
          for(let i=1; i < num_rows; i++){
            cy.get(`:nth-child(${i}) > .column-id > a`).then(($btn) => {
              let id_txt = $btn.text()
          
              //Click on ID Number
              cy.get(`:nth-child(${i}) > .column-id > a`)
                  .click()

              //Check that the url has the id_txt
              cy.url()
                  .and('contain',id_txt)

              cy.go(-1) //Go back 
            }) //Ends the Numbers of IDs loop
          } //Ends for loop
        }) //Ends the then((row)) loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten your code like this:

```js
cy.get('[href*="maps"]').each(($el) => {
  let id_text = $el.text().trim()

  //Check that the element is visible and click on it
  cy.wrap($el).should('be.visible').click()

  //Check that the url contains the text value of the element that was clicked on
  cy.url().should('contain', id_text)

  //Wait half a sec
  cy.wait(500)
})
```

Comment: That is much simpler! I still get the error where it says Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.should() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.

Comment: In order to help you more, please add the HTML to your question.

Comment: What part would you need to see? It is difficult for me to share too much.

Comment: I think your selector is causing the issue. You need to use a CSS selector. And to come with a CSS selector, I need to see at least two elements to figure out the common part,

Comment: Just the line of html the element is on? <a href="#/maps/432/show">432</a> and every line in the column is the same except the numbers are changed.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the css selector more? It is picking up on a button on a different part of the window unrelated to this. like href*="maps/\d/show"

Comment: You can look for any term that is specific to only the elements that you are targeting, could be `maps` or `show` or `#/maps` etc,

Comment: Wait I did href*="/show" and that worked for one iteration then wait back to saying the DOM element became detached

Comment: Try adding a bit of wait after the URL assertion. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you see **DOM element became detached** it means an action has made the page refresh and a previous query is no longer pointing at a valid element.

In you case, the action is the `.click()` and the list of elements selected by `cy.xpath('//span[text()="Id"]//following::a[contains(@href,"maps")]')` has been refreshed, so the list that Cypress is iterating over is no longer valid.

One approach to solving this is to separate the test into two loops.

```js
const links = [];   // save link info here

const selector = '//span[text()="Id"]//following::a[contains(@href,"maps")]';

cy.xpath(selector)
  .each(($el, index) => { 
    const id_text = $el.text()
    links.push(id_text)
    cy.xpath(selector).eq(index)
      .as(`maps${index}`)               // save a unique alias for this link
  }) 

cy.then(function() {
  links.forEach((link, index) => {

    // Check that the element is visible and click on it
    cy.get(`@maps${index}`)             // get the element from the alias      
      .should('be.visible')
      .click()

    //Check that the url contains the text value of the element that was clicked on
    cy.url().should('contain', link)

    cy.go('back')                       // return to start page
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The first part worked, it shows it stored all the elements I needed but then when it goes to click on them it says maps0 was never found

Comment: Sorry, I left out a character `@` in front of the alias name (when getting element from the alias). Will update.

Comment: Oh okay I think this is one the right track! I think I just need to make it visit the original url  after it checks the url. Because it stopped on the link it clicked on.

Comment: Yes that makes sense - start each check from a known position.

Comment: It must be iterating wrong, this shows now after visiting just the first link.                   The invalid subject you asserted on was:

  > Object{3}

Comment: That's from `cy.url()...`. It looks ok in theory. Can you find out what's in `Object(3)`?

Comment: It looks like it is the last element which is correct. I do not understand why it is trying to access it after the cy.visit(MAIN_URL). It is trying to wrap it I think?

Comment: I think even this approach is not good enough. When you `cy.visit()`  the browser resets (you will notice the page blanks out then redraws). The result is the links variable is getting reset. There is one more approach, I'll test it out and modify the answer.

Comment: I found the problem - `cy.wrap($el)` is no good for the alias, needed to query the specific link element from the original selector with `cy.xpath(selector).eq(index)`

Comment: And instead of `cy.visit()` I used `cy.go('back')` to return to the start page.

Comment: Awesome that is on the right track thank you! For some reason the second element (map1) is undefined, I need to see why that it with a cy.log

Comment: Figured it out, I will post the solution in the main body!